# Split columns in R by space delimiter

Tags: r

I have a dataset in the following format
`{r}
Name Start               End 
Abc  01/05/2015 00:00    01/06/2015 00:00
bbb  05/04/2015 00:00    05/05/2015 00:00`

I would like to convert this data frame in the following format

`{r}
Name Start      End        Month
Abc  01/05/2015 01/06/2015 January
bbb  05/04/2015 05/05/2015 May`

Essentially, I would like to split the columns based by a space delimiter and then convert each date to a month.

The name of my data frame is ba. Initially the date column was a factor and I converted it into a character. The I tried using strsplit().
`{r}
ba$time <- strsplit(ba$Start," ")`

and I get this output c("01/05/2016", "00:00")

Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We loop through the 2nd and 3rd columns ('Start', 'End') using `lapply`, match one or more space (`\\s+`) followed by characters till the end of the string and replace it with `''`, assign the output back.  Create the "Month" column by converting the 'Start' to `Date` class, extract the month using `format`.

```
ba[2:3] <- lapply(ba[2:3], sub, pattern="\\s+.*", replacement="")
ba$Month <- format(as.Date(ba$Start, format='%m/%d/%Y'), '%B')
ba
#  Name      Start        End     Month
#1  Abc 01/05/2015 01/06/2015   January
#2  bbb 05/04/2015 05/05/2015       May
```